# Android: получение типа защиты WiFi

Tags: android, wifi

Здравствуйте, в приложении вывожу характеристики сети WiFi. 
Не получается вывести поле с типом защиты сети. 
Подскажите, что делаю не так?
p.s. реализация через фрагменты

```
public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {

final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
final String[] securityModes = {"WEP", "PSK", "EAP", "WPA"};

for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
   return securityModes[i];
  }
 }
 return "OPEN";
}

//далее часть кода из onCreateView
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String currentSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
for (ScanResult result : results) {
 if (currentSSID.equals(result.SSID)) {

  String securityMode = getScanResultSecurity(result);

  if (securityMode.equals("WEP")) {
  textView_network92.setText("WEP");
  } else if (securityMode.equals("PSK")) {
  textView_network92.setText("PSK");
  }else if (securityMode.equals("EAP")) {
  textView_network92.setText("EAP");
  }else if (securityMode.equals("WPA")) {
  textView_network92.setText("WPA")  
  }else textView_network92.setText("OPEN");
 }
}
```

Comment: И где этот ``textView_network92`` потом используется? Значение присвоили, а показать забыли. Что пишется в логах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.startScan();   
List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
for (ScanResult result : results) {
   textView_network92.setText(result.capabilities);
}
```

И так же убедитесь, что у вас есть требуемые разрешения:

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

---

UPD. (спасибо @Timur)

Начиная с версии API 23+ так же требуется [следующее](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) разрешение

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Проверил наличие всех разрешений. 
Заметил такую проблему в логах: размер List<ScanResult> results = 0 в переменной `results.size();`

Comment: @Timur, дополнил ответ методом `startScan`

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Разобрался, проблема была в том, что для того чтобы `List<ScanResult>` был не нулем в ОС Android 6.0 и старше необходимо разрешение `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: @Timur, хорошо) Ну и возможно ваш вариант тоже работает, если вы после инициализации `wifiManager` будете вызывать `startScan()`

Comment: @Shakhov я попробовал Ваш вариант, но список тоже был пуст